# Format received long number as a decimal one with custom format

Tags: java

I'm receiving a number formatted as long. Although i'm receiving this number as a long I now that the last 3 digits correspond to a decimal part so I want to show the number formatted with grouping and a decimal separator.

Example: if I receive the number `11111111111` I want it to be shown like `11 111 111.111`

I have this code:

```
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat();
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    formatter.setGroupingUsed(true);
    symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
    formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);

    long valueAsLong = 11111111111L;
    double value = (double) valueAsLong / 1000;

    System.out.println(formatter.format(valueAsLong));
    System.out.println(formatter.format(value));
```

I want to know if I can achieve this without that cast, that is, setting a formatter that receives a `long` and format the number the way I want.

Comment: I think you should go throw on this: [Primitive data types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). The required output should be double so you have to cast your input to it. But you can also do it by autoboxing it: double `value = valueAsLong / 1000.0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No DecimalFormat doesn't support this, as it's purpose is to format a number as a String without changing it's value.

`format(longValue / 1000.0)` is the easiest solution, note however that it will not work for very large longs:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
        char decimalSeparator = decimalFormat.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator();

        // prints 123.456
        System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(123456 / 1000.0));

        // 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
        System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(Long.MAX_VALUE));

        // 9,223,372,036,854,776, not 9,223,372,036,854,776.807, as double's resolution is not sufficient
        System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(Long.MAX_VALUE / 1000.0));

        // 9,223,372,036,854,775.807
        BigInteger[] divAndRem = new BigInteger(Long.toString(Long.MAX_VALUE))
                .divideAndRemainder(new BigInteger("1000"));
        System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(divAndRem[0]) 
                + decimalSeparator + divAndRem[1]);

        // using String manipulation
        String longString = decimalFormat.format(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        System.out.println(new StringBuilder(longString).replace(
                longString.length() - 4, 
                longString.length() - 3, 
                Character.toString(decimalSeparator)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do it without casting, but it will need parsing with [java.text.DecimalFormat#parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition)), with `"#\u2030"` pattern, where `\u2030` is the `‰` (per-mille) character.

```
    long myLong = 123456L;
    String asPerMille = 
       new StringBuffer().append(myLong).append('\u2030').toString();

    DecimalFormat perMilleFormat = new DecimalFormat("#\u2030");        
    Number myLongAsDec = perMilleFormat.parse(asPerMille);

    System.out.println(
        String.format("%d can be parsed with pattern %s as a per-mille and gives %f", 
        myLong, 
        perMilleFormat.toPattern(), 
        myLongAsDec.doubleValue()));
```

The output is :

```
123456 can be parsed with pattern #‰ as a per-mille and gives 123.456000
```

Note that performance wise, your method is certainly better than building and parsing a `String` and then reformatting it with the different groupings.